# How to update component in UIViewController from Global class in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am new at swift development. Please help me to understand the situation to solve.

I want to update UIViewController from Global class. As I used callback function in Global class as it need to be control centrally.

```
class Global {

    static let global = Global()

    static func listener(msg:String) {
       if(topView = viewA)
          I want to update label of viewA
       else 
          I want to update label of viewB
    }
}

//This class is current view controller
class viewA:UIViewController {
 * has label
 * has button
}

class viewB:UIViewController {
 * has label2
 * has button
}
```

If used following solution but it give error

```
if(topView = viewA)
          topView.label = msg;   <- Error! Value of type UIVIEW has no member
       else 
          topView.label2 = msg;  <- Error! Value of type UIVIEW has no member
```

Comment: You can use NotificationCenter for the same and post a notification. You will have to add observer in all the classes you want to make the changes.

Comment: yes @Priyal is right. you can use NotifiactionCenter and Observers here.

Answer (score 1):

An authentic way is to use either `NSNotification` or `Delegates` to send message to a receiver, but at this point to remove this error `<- Error! Value of type UIVIEW has no member` you have to first cast your view to specific type of view to access the label inside that view.

e.g.,

```
if(topView = viewA)
     (topView as! viewA).label.text = msg;   <- Error! Value of type UIVIEW has no member
```

Notice this type cast `(topView as! viewA)`, in the above example.

Using NSNotification approach, you are open to send same message to more than one observers at a time. No need to type cast each time.